# How can i do deposit payment, down payment in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, payment

I am a beginner in coding and I am creating an appointment application. I would like to integrate the deposit in my Laravel appointment application. i.e. if a person makes an appointment for a service, he has to pay at least 30 percent of the amount of the service. How can I do this in Laravel?

To be more precise, I would like to give the users the possibility to pay either a part of the price (in percentage) or the totality of the payment.  I.e. if the price of a service costs 50€, the user will have the choice to pay either the total amount, or a part of it which can be set as a percentage of 20%, 30% of the initial amount. [as on the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEFnd.png)

Comment: If you want to integrate payments in your Laravel application then [cachier](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing) is a popular library to do this. However the code to integrate it and testing of the integration is on you. When you start using this (or something else) and have actual code with a specific coding problem you've encountered then you can ask a more specific question but the way this question is presented it's way too broad

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.